# Drupal: make a section invisible

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

is there any way to make a section invisible from template.php in drupal ?

Something like:

```
$form['name'] = array(
    '#visibility' => 'hidden',
...
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hook_form_alter is the standard way to change forms.

you can use `'#access' => FALSE`, if you wish to remove the item from the page. Or `'#type' => 'hidden'` to create a hidden form field. Drupal will not allow dynamic manipulation of a hidden fields (or at least one which has a value initally). If you want a hidden value which can be altered by a client side script try this:

```
$form['foo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#attributes'=>array('style'=>"display:none"),
    '#default_value' => $node->foo
  );
```